# What artefact repository I should use for continuous integration in c code?

Tags: jenkins, repository, integration, bamboo

What artefact repository I should use for continuous integration in c code?
The artefact repository should integrate with Jenkins or Bamboo or both. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're more than welcome to give Artifactory a try.

Using its [Jenkins](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Jenkins+%28Hudson%29+Artifactory+Plug-in) and [Bamboo](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Bamboo+Artifactory+Plug-in) plugin, you can [resolve custom dependencies from Artifactory and deploy your build outcomes to custom path in Artifactory](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-ConfiguringGeneric%28Freestyle%29Builds).

Comment: I was considering Artifactory for the same but not sure how can I manage maven dependencies for c code :(

Comment: I said nothing about maven :) Artifactory is not a maven only dependency manager (as opposite to some of its competitors). Please see the links, they are pointing to instructions on how to setup a "freestyle" build that can be used with any build tool (make included).